# Heroku Slug Size is 237MB the Repo Size is 70MB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

**Statistics**

```
Stack: Cedar
Framework: Ruby
Repo Size: 78.3MB
Slug Size: 237MB of 300MB
```

**Letter to Heroku Support**

My Slug Size has ballooned all the way up to 237MB. My repo size is only around 75MB. I've determined that the reason deals with my assets being stored multiple times in my slug, taking up unnecessary space.

I precompiled my assets the first time, so my images would appear on Heroku. I wanted to reduce my slug size, so I optimized my images. Trying to decrease loading time, I reduced the size of my images. I then precompiled them again. Instead of having the old images being replaced by the new ones, my slug size stored both sets of images.

I've ran heroku run bash, to open up my Application's Command Prompt. After that, I CD'd into my assets/images directory and ran ls. I discovered that in the path

```
app/assets/images
```

There are 3 sets of images.

and in the path

```
public/assets/images
```

There are 2 sets of images

This is an enormous albatross on my application and if I could fix this, I could reduce my slug size by at least half. I tried running in those directories

```
rmdir Dirname
```

but I can't delete them, because they have files in them.

I am trying to delete the unnecessary files that I didn't want in the first place. I've searched your documentation but you don't describe how to delete files from your slug.

I also don't want to lose any of the data in my app because it's taken a ton of time to build that data.

Please get back to me with answers to this question.

END LETTER

BASICALLY, this is an enormous albatross, and it's driving me crazy. I've tried running

```
heroku run bash
```

to enter the Command Prompt for my application

I cd'd into my application's app/assets/images directory and I didn't like what I saw. Under each subdirectory I saw THREE copies of every image. ARGHHHH! And under public/assets/images I saw two copies of every image.

I want to know if there's a way I can remove this albatross, because this is just such a waste of my time.

Comment: You may want to use a `.gitignore` file. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Comment: The old images will still be in your git history.

Comment: Then how do I delete them? They are an albatross that's eating up space.

Comment: Old versions of images in git history will not take up space in the slug. Only files in the head commit that are not ignored in `.gitignore` will be there.  This means two copies of every image (one in apps/assets, the other in public/assets).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that helps is adding a .slugignore file to the root of your project to tell Heroku not to compile certain files or directories into the slug. Mine looks like this:

```
*.psd
*.pdf
test
spec
features
doc
public
```

The public entry is in there because I serve all static files from Amazon's S3 service; just leave that line off if you're not using an external content-delivery system.

Answer (score 2):

I may have this wrong (and if I do, please correct me!), but here's what I've been doing with my assets when there have been any changes to them:

1. Clear out the existing asset manifest:

   ```
   rake assets:clean
   ```
2. Delete all files from the "public\assets" folder
3. Precompile production-version of assets:

   ```
   RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
   ```
4. Then commit & push to Heroku

You should end up with only one copy of the assets on Heroku this way.

Comment: This literally reduced my slug size by 2/3.  Well done!

Comment: I've been out of the Heroku loop for over two years now. I can't believe this still is useful info. :D

Answer (score 1):

The slug size includes the size of the gems you are using:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size

I would run a couple `$ du` commands on where ever your gems are installed and and try to find large ones.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udu.htm

With that in mind, if you are done adding gems to your project, it might not matter that you are close to the limit because 60 MB is a fair amount of code/image space to work with.  If you do have many more images to add, you might consider hosting them somewhere else.